# Как вывести число в теге <input> при изменении другого <input>?

Tags: javascript, input

Хочу чтобы при вводе значения в input, в другом input сразу же отображалось число с первого input переработанное функцией.

```js
function change() {
    var temp = document.getElementById("input1").value;
    document.getElementById("input2").innerHTML = temp * 2;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input id="input1" type="number" name="input1" min="0" placeholder="" oninput="change()"></p>
<p>
  <input id="input2" type="number" name="input2" min="0" placeholder="">
</p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Необходимо передавать значение input2 в value:

```js
function change() {
    var temp = document.getElementById("input1").value;
    document.getElementById("input2").value = temp * 2;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input id="input1" type="number" name="input1" min="0" placeholder="" oninput="change()"></p>
<p>
  <input id="input2" type="number" name="input2" min="0" placeholder="">
</p>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает. А чем value oт innerHTML отличается?

Comment: @WiAim innerHTML изменяет HTML-содержание тега, визуально твой ответ уходил вот сюда http://s32-temporary-files.radikal.ru/eec99ba1441d4cf3b3b6c56e4d66b203/-88693455.png:

Comment: innerHTML подошёл бы для textarea. Ещё для какой-то совместимости со старыми браузерами может быть стоит продублировать функцию в onchange=

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = document.createElement('input');
var i2 = document.createElement('input');
i2.oninput = function(){i.value = i2.value}
```